# Is there a way to combine html files and download them as excel file in python?

Tags: python, html, export-to-excel

I am pretty new to python, so my question might sound silly. I have downloaded several 'Well Completion' files from this link: https://wwwapps.emnrd.nm.gov/OCD/OCDPermitting/Reporting/Activity/WeeklyActivity.aspx. Now I want to combine all of the files into 1 excel sheet using Python and export it. So far, I have been pretty unsuccesful and I am hoping I will get an answer here. The problem lies in the fact that the files got downloaded in such a way that it opens with excel but it is actually in html format.

The code that I have used to combine the files is:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
output_doc = BeautifulSoup()
output_doc.append(output_doc.new_tag("html"))
output_doc.html.append(output_doc.new_tag("body"))
data_folder= r'C:\Users\dtsar\OneDrive\Desktop\another well completion'
for file in os.listdir(data_folder):
    if not file.lower().endswith('.html'):
        continue

    with open(file, 'r') as html_file:
        output_doc.body.extend(BeautifulSoup(html_file.read(), "html.parser").body)

print(output_doc.prettify())
```

but the response I got is:
`<html>`
`<body>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

I cannot understand where I am going wrong. The next step would be to export the data into an excel format but I cannot seem to combine all the files together in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: How many are there?  Wouldn't this be easier in a text editor?

Comment: I assume that the reports exist in HTML table form and should then be consolidated in an EXCEL. Since the server is not accessible at least from my location or runs into a timeout, a rough construction of the structure would be helpful. 

If necessary, the tables can be loaded directly with `pandas` and merged. An impression of the expected output structure would also be useful. Please no pictures but in text form. thanks

Comment: Hello Hedgehog, thank you for your response. Yes, they get downloaded as excel files but the data is still in html format. I already found the python code that I could use to convert the corrupt excel files into xlsx format. But thank you for your time. :-)

Comment: @TimRoberts what kind of text editor? I managed to use python to convert the files.

Comment: What editor do you use to write your code?  That will work.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the solution to change the broken excel files into proper .xlsx format. The code is below in case anybody needs it:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

folder_path = r'path to the folder'

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith(".xls"):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        with open(file_path) as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
        tables = soup.find_all('table')
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path.replace(".xls", ".xlsx"), engine='openpyxl')
        for i, table in enumerate(tables):
            caption = table.find('caption')
            if caption:
                sheet_name = caption.get_text().strip()
            else:
                sheet_name = 'Sheet{}'.format(i+1)
            df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
            writer.save()
```